# PrimeNG p-confirmDialog used in app.component.html not found in components injected by router-outlet

Tags: angular, primeng

I have a lot of p-confirmDialogs scattered around in my code. I wanted to use a single one in my app.component.html and then re-use that one.

In my `app.component.html` I use a router-outlet to determine which component is shown. It seems that when one of the injected components wants to use the p-confirmDialog of the `app.component.html` it is not found.

**app.component.html**

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<p-confirmDialog key="root-confirm">
</p-confirmDialog>
```

**foo.component.ts**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'foo-component',
})
this.confirmationService.confirm({
    key: 'root-confirm'
});
```

It seems to me that the confirmationService does not search in the scope of the app component if it is rendered in the router-outlet. I can get it to work if it is a direct child e.g. it is used as `<foo-component></foo-component>` instead of `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`.